# Add the character between two spaces

Tags: python, regex

I have the string:

```
string_str_____word
```

Where underscore represent spaces. I want to add "|" if space is repeated:

```
string_str_|_|_|_|_word
```

I tried this

```
re.sub(r'[ ]{2,}',' | ', word)
>string_str_|_word
```

But regex replaced everything.

Comment: The comma in `{2,}` means 2 or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are matching 2 or more spaces using `[ ]{2,}` and replacing that with  `|` .

But you want to match a single space to be replaced with a single space and pipe while there is a space following.

You could use a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert a space on the right.

In the replacement use a space and a pipe. (The square brackets are not required)

`[ ](?=[ ])`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dhR45U/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/puxeBk)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookahead to avoid consuming the second space:

```
import re

word = 'string str     word'

print(re.sub(r' (?= )', ' |', word))
```

Output:

```
string str | | | | word
```